# View based NSTableView checkbox

Tags: checkbox, nstableview

I have an NSTableView that's view based, not the old cell based, and I'm doing everything via bindings.  In one of my columns I now want a checkbox.  I dragged a checkbox button (not a checkbox button cell) inside of the column's "Table Cell View".

[image: IB Image]

Then I deleted the "Table View Cell" and its child.  When I run, I don't see any checkboxes in the column.  What's the right way to do this?